# JQuery modal dialog shows behind overlay using append

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div with some stuff on I want to pop up to the user so they have to agree before they submit:

```
<div id="terms" style="display:none">
        <p style="font-weight:bold">If your data is not backed up in advance, you may have to forfeit your booked slot and rebook the handover on another date.</p>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTerms" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="error" Style="font-size:0.8em" Text =" I understand the above, and will ensure my data is backed up prior to the handover date" runat="server" /> 
        <p style="text-align:right"><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Enabled="False" /></p>
    </div>
```

I'm using a jQuery UI dialog to achieve this:

```
    $('#terms').css('visibility','block');
    $('#terms').dialog({ 
           modal: true, 
           width: '500px', 
           title: 'IMPORTANT! Remember To Backup Your Laptop', 
           open: function (event, ui) { 
                 $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide(); 
                 $(this).parent().appendTo('form'); }, 
     });
```

If I leave out:

```
$(this).parent().appendTo('form'); }
```

the button will not fire as it has been outside of the form.

However, when I put it in to make the button work, the form appears behind the modal overlay and is unclickable.

I'm using a master page - not sure if this relevant.

Comment: Did you try changing your z-indexes around? Any time something is behind or in front of something on a web page, you need to modify your z-index.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the dialog to the document node instead, and add an event handler to the button that calls `form.submit()`.

Comment: This handler can be added using the `buttons` option when opening the dialog : http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be happening only with the latest version of JQuery and if you use the append option.

Unfortunately, submitting the form from JQuery when the control is in an UpdatePanel causes the entire page to refresh.

This snippet will allow you to append the dialog to the Form and keep the overlay behind it by setting the z-index on the overlay and dialog.

```
open: function (type, data) {
                $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index', 103);
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index', 102);
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
```